# Calorie Counter Java

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm self-teaching myself Java and came across this question.

It required the making of multiple methods and also taking user data and making it into an array.

I am confused because wouldn't an array only have to be either a float, or a int or a double or a String, it cant be both a String and a double. But the user is entering multiple flavors of data. I am adding the question below and also the code I have scripted so far.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvNOi.png)
I have attached an image of the question

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class salesRecord {

    String Itemname;
    int Quantity;
    float unitPrice;
    static float total;
    String status; //for credit or debit

    void data() {

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Item name: ");
        Itemname=input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your Quantity: ");
        Quantity=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your Unit Price: ");
        unitPrice=input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("What is your Status: ");
        status=input.next();

        total=Quantity*unitPrice;

    }

    void ShowData() {


        System.out.println("Item name is: "+Itemname);
        System.out.println("Quantity is: "+Quantity);
        System.out.println("Price per unit is: "+unitPrice);
        System.out.println("Credit or Debit: "+status);
        System.out.println("Total Price is: "+ total);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        salesRecord cus1=new salesRecord();
        Scanner inputcashier=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many items do you have: ");
        int items=inputcashier.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {

            cus1.data();
            cus1.ShowData();
            total=total+total;
        }

        System.out.println("Your grand total is: "+total);

    }


}
```

Comment: You'll be wanting an array of `SalesRecord` objects, because each such object has a couple of strings and a couple of numbers inside.

Answer (score 0):

The problem states that you need to hold data of multiple types, an object is the best way to hold this data. You would first need to create the `SalesRecord`.

```java
class SalesRecord{
  String itemName;
  double unitPrice;
  double total;
  String status;

  // constructor 
  SalesRecord(String _itemName,double _unitPrice,double _total,String _status){
    this.itemName = _itemName;
    this.unitPrice = _unitPrice;
    this.total = _total;
    this.status = _status;
  }
}
```

Once you have created this object the problem then states to store them in an array size 10 called `salesRecord`

```java
SalesRecord[] salesRecord = new SalesRecord[10];
```

This array will now hold the `SalesRecord` objects. Thus has the type `SalesRecord` rather than your typical int,string or double.

[Here's a good intro to creating and storing objects.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8yjkWGRlUmY)

Comment: Would I then need to make a loop to store the 10 objects in that array?

Comment: Yes, you would need to create a loop to loop over the size of the array (10) and then in the loop you would add each item by doing `thearrayofsize10[i] = theobjectyouradding`